# Stack Overflow for Teams support missing / unclear log in functionality

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-for-teams, login

### Background

I am trying to implement Stack Overflow for Teams where I work (one milestone is to have at least 100 active users) and I am already using technical support provided by Stack Overflow. However, I have realized that tickets can be submitted also without being logged in and thus there will be no stored history.

### The actual issue

If I access support I see the menu as below:

[image: Support without being logged in]

Somehow I remember that I can be logged in in the ticketing system (this seems to be outside of being logged in into Stack Overflow + private team) and using a link from the history (https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/login) I am able to also login in here:

[image: Teams support login]

After logging in, I can see my old tickets (only those issued while being logged in I think) and the menu is adjusted accordingly:

[image: Teams support menu when being logged in]

This whole thing is quite confusing as I want to be able to manage all tickets in one place (one issued ticket is invisible for me as I only have the reference number and).

So my issue is: Stack Overflow for Teams support missing / unclear log in functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That part of our support portal was intentionally broken. There were a bunch of features in there that we weren't comfortable with being public when we first started using this software, and we had much higher priorities at the time (namely, actually getting everything set up and starting to use the software) than trying to work out what we wanted users to have access to in there and making all the necessary changes. Our simple and straight-forward solution was to delete a bunch of stuff to mostly disable access to it.

Now that we have some more time and flexibility to look into this in more detail, we've realized that we actually can make some of the necessary changes and get that system to a point where we're comfortable enabling end-user access. This will be strictly limited to viewing your past tickets. You'll be able to view a list of all your tickets and view each individual ticket.

We've gone ahead and made most of the necessary changes to the ticket list and details pages. We're still testing them out a bit to make sure they all function correctly, and then we'll look into the login page and what we can do to make sure users can view their past ticket history, as well as re-adding some of the login options to the header.

To be clear, though: you will **only** ever be able to view tickets assigned to the email address you've used to login. We will not be experimenting with any functionality that allows you to enter ticket details and view it anonymously.

---

**Update:** Most of these changes are now live, including the addition of the login links in the header. Your login for here on the site will **not** work in the support system - there's just no possible way we can get that functionality to work. Currently, we still have non-agent login disabled, which means you can't yet request a password reset in order to "register" your account and login, but there is a bug that allows you to bypass that check when using the Google login option, so feel free to do that for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

We actually don't support users logging into our support portal to view tickets. The reason being is that we use a ton of automation to allow a small team to handle a large volume of tickets. This automation has a habit of importing information that shouldn't be publically viewable and there's no way to reliably hide it.

We're actually puzzled as to how you stumbled onto the login page, we thought we deleted all references to it.

Comment: I am not sure how I got there (I think there was a link somewhere so I have just messed up with the URL a little bit, as it is very friendly). However, it looks like a very good functionality as it allows the client to have an overview of the entire support history. Currently I have created ticket without being logged in and all I have is a number as opposed of being logged in and seeing the activity for it. So, unless there is a very good reason to scrap it, I would greatly appreciate to keep it.